# After call to scrollToRowAtIndexPath, setContentOffset has no effect

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am trying to accomplish the following:

- hide the search bar
- scroll the table to the first row

This code accomplishes the goal, but leaves a huge white gap where the search bar used to be:

```
[self.theSearchBar setHidden:YES];
NSIndexPath *pathToFirstRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:pathToFirstRow atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Normally I use this to hide the scroll bar:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44) animated:YES];
```

But after the call to scrollToRowAtIndexPath, it has no effect.

Is there either some way to make this work, or some other way to accomplish the same thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Every scroll view has a frame property which specifies the relative postion with respect to its parent view and its size. You can access it using scrollview.frame and set it by assigning a rectangle to it. scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height).

Comment: Hey i read your question again. I have few questions. Is search bar part of tableview? Can you put the tableview and searchbar into seperate containers ?

Comment: The search bar is in the table view header;  it's actually the search bar portion of the searchDisplayController.  (oops, hit return and saved the comment).  I got it working with changing the frame, though - thanks!  And thanks for the upvotes.  If you move this to a real answer I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting the frame of your scrollview to remove the gap.

Comment: This worked - self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -44, 320, 480); after the call to scrollToRowAtIndexPath and then self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480 - 44); to move it back after turning the search bar back on.